# How do I add a space between each comment in Rmarkdown when the output is text from a code chunk?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have some data which includes comments in an excel file. After importing into R, I would like to add the comments at the bottom of some analysis in `RMarkdown`. I passed the column to a code chunk and it knits the output. Here is a screenshot -
[image]

As you can see, it's a bit chunked up. Is there a way for me to

1. Add a space between each number line
2. Possibly replace the numbers with bullet points
3. Fix the text cutting off. See highlighted. The word is "of", but it cuts the "f" to a new line. There are a lot of lines like this. Is there any way to fix that too?

I know how to add spacing when type n the text, however since this is the output of a code chunk, I have no idea how to add the spacing. I have looked online, however, all solutions show how to add spacing when you type in the text as opposed to text from a code chunk.

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example?

Comment: @henrik_ibsen it's hard to reproduce since the data I'm using is from a csv file. I've tried typing comments in R and knitting but it does not produce the same output as when I upload the comments from a csv file.

Comment: At the very least provide the code that outputs the comments and some information about the chunk options and YAML-header. Also, what is different between the comments you type in R and the ones in your .csv-file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have any special functions or settings affecting the output from your chunk, generating a list from your text can be achieved in the following way

````
---
output: pdf_document
---


```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
textTest <- c("I have never seen our strategic plan, if we have one", 
              "Yes, to corporate partners and high net worth, I have not 
              heard about an effort to build relationships with leaders of 
              color, labor leaders, faith leaders, etc.")

cat(paste0("- ", textTest, "\n"))
```
````

`results='asis'` is needed to get the correct text output from the chunk. As for the line `cat(paste0("- ", textTest, "\n"))`:

- `"- "` generates the list structure. The lagging space is necessary if using `paste0()`. Can be omitted if using `paste()` .
- `"\n"` generates new lines. Use double (`"\n\n"`) to get more space between list entries.

Consequently, the output in R will look like this

```
- I have never seen our strategic plan, if we have one
 - Yes, to corporate partners and high net worth, I have not 
              heard about an effort to build relationships with leaders of 
              color, labor leaders, faith leaders, etc.
```

Which will be knitted into

- *I have never seen our strategic plan, if we have one*
- *Yes, to corporate partners and high net worth, I have not
  heard about an effort to build relationships with leaders of
  color, labor leaders, faith leaders, etc.*

for pdf, word and html